# Adding console input to ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, input, console, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to add items from the console input and scanner input to arraylists in java.
(To run the program user types Program ID)

The problem is that each time I run the program the contents of the arraylists update to only what has been entered that time. I would like the arraylists to contain all of the inputs that have been entered.

```
public class User{

private static List<String> listNames = new ArrayList<String>();
private static List<Integer> listIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int tempID = 5000;
        if (args.length>0) tempID= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Login  "+tempID);
  
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your Name : ");
        tempName = scanner.nextLine();
        
        User n = new User();
        n.ID= tempID;
        n.name = tempName;
        listIds.add(n.ID);
        listNames.add(n.name);

        }
     }


}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Obviously you're new to this, so using a Database system is probably not a good place to start. Look up how to read and write to TEXT files for somewhere to start with...

Answer (score 0):

Every time you compile your program you create new Arrays. So you need another way of saving your inputs like in a SQL Database or you can run your program infinitely with a loop and ask each time for a new entry and collect it with the scanner like you already did but with that method, you can do nothing with the array entries because your asking for entries never stops.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you run the program it is going to initialize a different array. To solve this, you can store your data in a database such as MySQL or Oracle. But a more efficient way to solve this is that to save your ArrayList as an object locally using `java.io.ObjectInputStream` and `java.io.ObjectOutputStream`
I wrote the following 2 functions

```
public static ArrayList<Object> loadArrayList(String filename)
{
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        ArrayList<Object> arr = (ArrayList<Object>) ois.readObject();
        return arr;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (ois != null) {
            try {
                ois.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}   
public static void saveArrayList(ArrayList<Object> arr, String filename)

{
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
        oos.writeObject(arr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (oos != null) {
            try {
                oos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call `saveArrayList` with the first argument is your ArrayList instance and the second argument the filename. You can then load from your local file system using the `loadArrayList` method with the argument is your filename. 
In your case, just call the `saveArrayList` method when your user exits the program and call the `loadArrayList` to get all your elements from the previous inputs to resume the user's progress

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I'm a bit confused about why I would load in a file though?

Comment: Because when you store your ArrayList as an object in the local file system, its there in a file, and when your program start again it needs to get the data that already exists in the ArrayList, in order to do so, you need to load the file from the local file system.